# Spine and 2D Unity Weird Light Issue

Tags: unity, lighting, materials, normal-mapping, spine

While using spine in unity 2D with a spot light, the light from the spot light will shine on the character if he's facing right but only when the light is in front (in the Z direction) of the character. If the character turns left the light will not have any affect. But, if you turn left and move the light behind (in the Z direction) of the character, then the light will shine on the character. I'm using the Spine/Skeleton Lit or Spine/SkeletonGraphic material with spine 3.6 runtime. I've tried adjusting the alpha and other random settings, but im not sure where to begin.

The Z direction of the character doesn't change when turning left or right in unity, but the spot light only affects in a certain direction.

The environmental light affects the character, but the spot light only affects the character based on the rotation. I want the spot light to affect the character regardless of their X scale or rotation. Culling is off....

Answer (score 1):

"When you've been working on a problem for 1 hour, ask a question on a forum, and then solve your problem 3 minutes after asking the question" = SMH.

The problem is that im rotating my character 180 directions when facing left.  Therefore, the normals are away from the spot light.  I solved the problem by changing the X scale from 1 to -1.  This will allow the light to affect the character while facing left or right.